# Caching aggregrate results of user supplied queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an application which let users track visitors on their own website. For this I have a table `visitors(id, email, sessions, first_seen, last_seen, ...)`

Users of my application can save filters/groups of visitors matching certain conditions on attributes. For this I have a table called like

`groups(id, visitor_id, name, filters[{type, field, amount}...])`

Example of a `filters[]`

(`type: "greater_than", field: "sessions", amount: 5`)

Each group can have multiple filters and for each group, I'd like to display the amount of visitors/results that match the filters.

What is the best way to handle this in the database?

I am thinking of something like a materialized view, but I'd still want the data to be fresh and up to date and not sure if this is the best approach.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Construct the query in the application layer and then call it.

Comment: Yeah, but if I have to count the number of results for every `group` a user has specified (5-20), every time they load the page, perhaps it's not best approach considering performance.